# Autoadvancing gallery animation

Tags: android, animation, android-gallery

I have a Gallery widget set up to auto advance every 10000ms.  However the transition between views is instantaneous and I would prefer to have a transition.

My advancing method is like so:

```
private void tickerAdvance() {
    int selectedItemPosition = mTickerGallery.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (selectedItemPosition + 1 == mTickerGallery.getCount()) {
        mTickerGallery.setSelection(0, true);
    } else {
        mTickerGallery.setSelection(selectedItemPosition + 1, true);
    }
}
```

I was under the impression that setting the animation to true would cause it to animate between states.  In my XML I've also added animationDuration="500", however the transition still pops between states instantly.

Comment: i don't know how you doing but i have one made with horizontalscrollview that makes transition animation by just setting animation on the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I came up with is that the Gallery API is terribly non-extensible.  There are multiple package private or private methods that would unlock this functionality without a kludge including moveNext, FlingRunnable.startwithdistance, and scrollToChild. Alas, they are all unavailable.

Instead the best answer I was able to come up with was to override setSelection to get all the behaviors I needed.  In the setSelection method I reverse the deceleration algorithm to calculate a velocity for a calculated distance and then call onFling. This is a nasty kludge could be made a ton better by making any of the above methods protected or public (I can't fathom a reason why at least moveNext and scrollToChild shouldn't be).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have used the **setSelection()** which obviously won't give you the feel of an Gallery being scrolled. SO instead of using **setSelection()** you have to override the **onScroll()** of gallery.

Here is how you do it.

Assuming that you have made the necessary steps for auto advancing periodically, now do this code.

```
MotionEvent e1, e2;
gallery.onScroll(e1, e2, scroll_limit   , 0);    //scroll limit is your integer variable for scroll limit.
```

Comment: Unless I'm misusing something, onScoll doesn't seem to have better behavior.  Though this lead me to consider using onFling which would have appropriate behavior.  Both approaches bother me though because I don't like the idea of using gesture event handlers like this...but it might be the only reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar task to make item to item animation and i decided to choose gallery, so i tried a lot of things, but the best way is to subclass gallery and add this:

boolean avoidSound = false;

```
public void showNext() {
    avoidSound = true;
    this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
}


public void playSoundEffect(int soundConstant) {
    if (avoidSound) {
        avoidSound = false;
    } else {
        super.playSoundEffect(soundConstant);
    }
}
```

just call showNext() and it will do an animation